# How to initialise Angular components with signal inputs from test?

Tags: angular, angular-signals

Let's say I have a simple component with signal input introduced in Angular 17.1

```
@Component({
  selector: 'greet',
  template: `
    <span class="greet-text">{{firstName()}}</span>`,
  standalone: true,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class GreetComponent {
  firstName = input.required<string>();
}
```

How can I instantiate this component from `TestBed` and assign signal inputs?

The only [solution I found in Angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e2272750878e1f74e59121e76a01e910ad1ac607/integration/cli-signal-inputs/src/app/greet.component.spec.ts#L20-L27), it to wrap it into another component without signal input.

Is it the only way to test new inputs? Doubling number of components...

```
describe('greet component', () => {
  it('should allow binding to an input', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestCmp);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
});

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  template: `<greet [firstName]="firstName" />`,
  imports: [GreetComponent],
})
class TestCmp {
  firstName = 'Initial';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated in docs of `InputFuction` interface, `InputSignal` is non-writable:

```js
/**
 * `InputSignal` is represents a special `Signal` for a directive/component input.
 *
 * An input signal is similar to a non-writable signal except that it also
 * carries additional type-information for transforms, and that Angular internally
 * updates the signal whenever a new value is bound.
 *
 * @developerPreview
 */
```

However, [Alex Rickabaugh](https://github.com/alxhub) pointed out in this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682#discussioncomment-5515663):

> When you create a component "dynamically" (e.g. with `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`) then you "control" the component and its inputs via its `ComponentRef`. `ComponentRef` has `.setInput` to update the values for inputs of that component.
>
> In tests, `ComponentFixture` exposes the `.componentRef` so you can use `.setInput` to test the component by manipulating its inputs. All of this works today, and will work with signal components too.

This now works with [jest-preset-angular](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/commit/7f7a22f3ab4068a7574f64e37f819a0eff3e86c3) v14.0.2 and Angular 17.3.2.

### Example

```js
import { ComponentRef } from '@angular/core'
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { GreetComponent } from './greet.component'

describe('GreetComponent', () => {
  let component: GreetComponent
  let componentRef: ComponentRef<GreetComponent>
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GreetComponent>

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [GreetComponent],
    }).compileComponents()

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GreetComponent)

    component = fixture.componentInstance
    componentRef = fixture.componentRef
    componentRef.setInput('firstName', 'Feyd-Rautha')
    fixture.detectChanges()
  })

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Comment: Yes, does not work to set inputs with setInput. I got the same error.

Comment: this is currently blocked by https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/2246

Answer (score -2):

There is now solution, in new Angular 17.3.0 there is new feature called model. And this model behaves like input but with two way data binding.

This means, that if you don't need your input to be read only, change it to model and then you can happily set value in your unit test without any problem.

here is link to angular docs https://angular.dev/guide/signals/model

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a valid solution to the original question about signal _inputs_. Changing these inputs to _models_ just for testing would not be a good idea.

Comment: I don't say that changing models for test is good idea, I say that it is alternative solution which can bring some benefits over dealing with plain input.